# Number of active sku's by days

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have this table (products with information about start and end publish
):

```
SKU  start_time            end_time
id1   21.01.2020 14:10:00    22.01.2020 16:18:05
id1   23.01.2020 16:18:05    24.01.2020 19:03:14
id2   21.01.2020 16:18:05    21.01.2020 18:33:50
id3   25.01.2020 18:33:50    25.01.2020 19:03:14
```

and expect active products by days in two variants (not include comments in braces):

```
date            active_sku    active sku_end_of_day
21.01.2020      2 (id1,id2)   1 (id1)
22.01.2020      1 (id1)       0
23.01.2020      1 (id1)       1 (id1)
24.01.2020      1 (id1)       0
25.01.2020      1 (id3)       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Assuming that `start_time` and `end_time` are timestamps data type - consider below

```
select date, 
  count(distinct SKU) as active_sku, 
  count(distinct if(offset = 0, null, SKU)) as active_sku_end_of_date
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(array_reverse(generate_date_array(date(start_time),date(end_time)))) date with offset
group by date
# order by date
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In case if `start_time` and `end_time` are strings - you should use `parse_timestamp()` function to parse timestamp from string - as in below example

```
select date, 
  count(distinct SKU) as active_sku, 
  count(distinct if(offset = 0, null, SKU)) as active_sku_end_of_date
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(array_reverse(generate_date_array(date(parse_timestamp('%d.%m.%Y %T', start_time)),date(parse_timestamp('%d.%m.%Y %T', end_time))))) date with offset
group by date
# order by date
```

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up (if not yet) :o)